# .htaccess rewrite with multiple regex and GET value assignment

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I don't have problem setting a GET variable when there is no regular expression in the rewrite rule. For example the following works as expected, when I execute `sample.html?test=OK` the `test` variable in `sample.php` is set as `OK`.

```
RewriteRule ^sample.html sample.php [NC]
```

The problem starts when there is regular expression in the rewrite rule. For example the following is not working as the above one.

```
RewriteRule ^sample-(.*).html sample.php?one=$1 [NC]
```

I want to execute URL like `sample-123.html?test=OK` while I have both `one` and `test` get their values in `sample.php`.

I've read multiple questions in here but non were answering this type of problem. I saw different answers suggesting using `RewriteCond`. I tried them but with no luck, as I'm not expert in .htaccess at all.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://mod-rewrite-cheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need `QSA` flag here:

```
RewriteRule ^sample-(.+)\.html$ sample.php?one=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.